# Using Vlookup/Macros to Transpose

Tags: excel, macros, vlookup, transpose

In Excel, I have a unique listing of people and their various roles that they hold in separate columns within each row as following:

**Name**           **Role**         **Role**          **Role**          **Role**           **Role** 
John                A                 B                    C                     null            null  
Jane                D                 C                  null                     null            null  
Lisa                A                 B                    C                       F              G

I want to transpose all the roles for each unique 'Name' so that there is a row for each combination of Name - Role as follows:

**Name**    **Role**  
John       A
John       B
John       C
Jane       D
Jane       C
Lisa       A
Lisa       B
Lisa       C
Lisa       F
Lisa       G

Is there any combination of functions or macros I can utilize to get this output in another sheet or the same spreadsheet? Even if the transposed rows includes null values, I can go in and delete all rows with blank values at the end. I have about 30+ users and many have 20+ roles that I'm trying to separate so this may save me time if there's an automated way to do it.

Comment: Array is your friend.

Comment: You can use `Power Pivot` or, if you have Office 365 / Excel 2016, `Get and Transform` to `UnPivot` the `Role` columns.

Answer (score 3):

In H2:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,CEILING((ROW()-1)/COUNTA($B$1:$F$1),1),0)
```

In I2:

```
=VLOOKUP(H2,$A$2:$F$4,COUNTIF(H$2:H2,H2)+1,FALSE)
```

Fill both down.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This will list all the names and exclude nulls as long as the nulls exist for each person as the right most cells. (Meaning there is no pattern like `A, B, Null, C, Null, D`).

[image]

H2 = `=COUNTA(B2:F2)`, drag down

A7 = `=A2`

A8 = `=IF(COUNTIF($A$7:A7,A7)<VLOOKUP(A7,$A$2:$H$4,8,0),A7,OFFSET(A$1,MATCH(A7,$A$1:$A$4,0),0))`, drag down for `names * roles` rows

B7 = `=OFFSET($A$1,MATCH($A7,$A$1:$A$4,0)-1,COUNTIF($A$7:$A7,$A7))`, drag down
for `names * roles` rows

**EDIT:**

To eliminate column H, change the formula in A8 to the below:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$7:A7,A7)<COUNTA(OFFSET($A$1,MATCH(A7,$A$1:$A$4,0)-1,1,1,COUNTA($A$1:$F$1))),A7,OFFSET(A$1,MATCH(A7,$A$1:$A$4,0),0))
```